# Getting exception System.InvalidOperationException while trying to get data from db

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I'm trying to get data from oracle db table in C# console application.
But all I get is System.InvalidOperationException with following description:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>      at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
>      at GetDataFromOracleDb.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\GetDataFromOracleDb\GetDataFromOracleDb\Program.cs:line 26

My C# code is:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {
        var cs = "Data Source=DEMO;User Id=taxworker;Password=password;";

        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(cs)) {
            conn.Open();

            var query = "select * from testtable";

            using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn)) {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                Console.WriteLine(dr.Read());
                Console.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

The same query in SQL Developer returns 3 rows.

Also I tried to get data from random tabel under "system" user and got all rows and no exceptions. To do that I changed connection string and query:

```
var cs = "Data Source=DEMO;User Id=system;Password=admin;";
var query = "select * from help";
```

My questions are: 
Why I'm getting this exception?
What I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `Console.WriteLine(dr.Read())`? Is it true or false?

Comment: is there actually data in there?

Comment: @BugFinder, yes

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it's false. P.S.: when I try to query for count(*) dr.Read() returns true but dr[0].ToString() returns 0. (Maybe it will help)

Comment: @IliaMikhailov: well, then there is no data in the table. If you use `SELECT COUNT(*)` you will always get a result because then you would get `0` if the table is empty. That's the reason for the error because you can't use `dr[0]` if the reader don't hold a record.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, but the same query from oracle sql developer returns data so actually table is not empty

Comment: Check connection string, database name and so on

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy, I think connection string is correct because connection opens with no exceptions

Comment: Show please a screenshot from  from OracleSql developer where connection settings are visible

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy, sql developer connections' screenshots: https://postimg.cc/gallery/h7ce59bc/

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy, problem solved! I wanted to reboot my machine and when I tried to close sql developer it asked me what to do whith uncommited changes in database under worker connection. I chose "commit changes" and tried to run C# application one more time. And this time I got all data.